# How to make that typeahead shows info from mysql using nodejs and ajax

Tags: mysql, node.js, ajax, express, typeahead.js

Hi I'm trying to use typeahead to show the info from my local DB (Mysql) using nodejs and express but it's not working

I already tried using this tutorial https://codeforgeek.com/ajax-search-box-using-node-mysql/ but it's not working and I don't know what else i can do

createSesions.js

```
router.get('/add/search', isLoggedIn, (req, res) =>
{
    dbConnection.query('SELECT fullname FROM pacientes WHERE fullname LIKE ?"%' + req.query.key + '%"',
        (err, rows, fields) =>
        {
            if (err) throw err;
            var data = [];
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
            {
                data.push(rows[i].fullname);
            }
            res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    );
});
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead(
    {
        name: 'paciente',
        remote: 'http://localhost:3000/createSesiones/add/search?key=%QUERY',
        limit: 10
    });
});
```

The Input

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead tt-query" name="paciente"
     placeholder="Asignar paciente" autofocus required>
</div>
```

I expect to work like this but showing the info from my db

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by removing the "?"

from this:

```
dbConnection.query('SELECT fullname FROM pacientes WHERE fullname LIKE ?"%' + req.query.key + '%"',
```

To this:

```
dbConnection.query('SELECT fullname FROM pacientes WHERE fullname LIKE "%' + req.query.key + '%"',
```

and updating jquery